# Reading singleValueExtendedProperties of an email attachment

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365

I have an email message which has another email message as an attachment.

I am trying to read the `singleValueExtendedProperties` of the attached email message using below query, but it doesn't work.

I don't see `singleValueExtendedProperties` in the response.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{mailbox}/mailFolders/Inbox/messages/
{messageId}/attachments/{attachmentId}?$expand=microsoft.graph.itemattachment/
item($expand=microsoft.graph.message/singleValueExtendedProperties(
$filter = id eq 'string 0x001A'))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), `singleValueExtendedProperties` are not available at mail attachment level.

Supported resources for `singleValueExtendedProperties` are:

- calendar
- contact
- contactFolder
- event
- mailFolder
- message
- group calendar
- group event
- group post

When an email message with `singleValueExtendedProperties` is attached to the another email then `singleValueExtendedProperties` are lost.

Comment: I have to retrieve the item class of the attached email message. In graph API, it is only available in the value of property: string 0x001A. How else do I retrieve the itemclass of the attached email message?